# Quotation marks turn to question marks 

Tags: ruby, parsing, encoding, utf-8

So I have a **ruby** script that parses HTML pages and saves the extracted string into a DB...
but i'm getting weired charcters (usually question marks) instead of plain text...

Eg : â€˜SOME TEXTâ€™ instead of 'Some Text'

I've tried HTML entities and CGI::unescape ... but to no avail...
did some googling n set $KCODE = 'u' & require 'jcode'
still not working...

any suggestions /pointers would be great

Thanks

PS : using mysql 5.1

Answer (score 4):

Your script is storing the Unicode escape sequences for quotation marks (instead of ASCII quotation marks) in the database.

That's actually good - it shows that the DB itself is working fine, although for best results you should ensure that the table is set to use 'utf8_collation_ci' so that string sorting works properly.

The fact that the output is *displayed* as "â€˜" just means that your terminal (and/or web page) *output* encoding is incorrect.

If it's terminal output, make sure that `$ENV{'LANG'}` is set to the appropriate UTF8 encoding (e.g. `en.UTF-8`) and that the terminal emulator itself is set the same way.

If it's HTML output, make sure that the page encoding is set to `UTF-8` as well, i.e.:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Is the DB that you're storing data in capable of handling Unicode? These symptoms seem to imply that it's not. For Unicode support under MySQL, please see [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode.html).

It seems likely that the quotation marks in question are not the standard ASCII quotation marks but the [Unicode ones](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html).

Ruby has an `iconv` implementation to convert between encoding types. See [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/iconv/rdoc/index.html) for more information.

Comment: but note that you only need to _convert_ encoding if the original page wasn't in UTF-8 and you want to store your copy in UTF-8

Comment: ... or it was in UTF-8 and you don't want to store it in UTF-8.